# How to find the median of different-sized lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numbers which I want to sort into bins and find the median of each bin. If the bins all had the same number of data points, this would be easy to do reasonably efficiently using numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np    
indices=np.array([0,1,0,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,0,2])
length=np.max(indices)+1
data = np.arange(len(indices))
binned = np.array([data[indices == i] for i in range(length)])
```

The binned data (in the array `binned`) is then

```
array([[ 0,  2, 10],
   [ 1,  3,  4],
   [ 5,  9, 11],
   [ 6,  7,  8]])
```

The median of each bin is:

```
np.median(binned, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
array([2., 3., 9., 7.])
```

However, if the list is such that there are different numbers of points in each bin (or no points in some of the bins), I can't create a numpy array or use np.median and instead have to do the heavy lifting in a for loop:

```
indices=np.array([0,1,1,1,3,1,1,0,0,0,3])
data = np.arange(len(indices))
```

The binned data is

```
[data[indices == i] for i in range(length)]

[array([0, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([ 4, 10])]
```

But I can't take a median of the list of arrays. Instead, I can do

```
[np.median(data[indices == i]) for i in range(length)]
```

and get

```
[7.5, 3.0, nan, 7.0]
```

But that for loop is pretty slow. (I have a few million data points and tens or hundreds of thousands of bins in my real data.)

Is there a way to do this that avoids heavy reliance on for loops (or even gets rid of for loops altogether)?

Comment: change 4 by a function that determine the size

Comment: Done. (Changed 4 to ```length```).

Comment: I don't think there will be a different way to get a median of lists of different sizes. If there exists a way, it will be a wrapper because for different sizes you need to consider a different algorithm, which effectively is a for loop.

Comment: Depending on the diversity of bin sizes it may be useful to group bins with same size together.

Comment: Interesting idea @MichaelButscher, but there probably won't be many (if any) same-sized bins in my particular case. (It's millions of data points being grouped into tens of thousands of bins, so the bin sizes are large enough that they'll vary by at least one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your two columns in a `pandas` DataFrame and you can easily compute your medians by grouping by 'indices'. Let's see it in practice :

```
import numpy as np , pandas as pd

indices = [0,1,1,1,3,1,1,0,0,0,3]
data = np.arange(len(indices))

df = pd.DataFrame({"indices": indices, "data": data}) # Your DataFrame
df.head() # Take a look

    indices data
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   3   4
medians = df.groupby("indices").median()# median for each value of `indices`
medians  
        data
    indices 
    0   7.5
    1   3.0
    3   7.0

# Finding indices with no data point
desired_indices = pd.Series([0, 1, 10, -5, 2])
is_in_index = desired_indices.isin(medians.index)
has_no_data = desired_indices[~ is_in_index]
has_no_data
2    10
3    -5
4     2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Brilliant; that does it, and in a second or so for my large data set, whereas it was taking multiple hours with the for loop.

A followup: is there an easy way to identify the bins with no data? (I really do want the nan in bin 2, and I want the bins in index order.)

Comment: I've added a piece of code to find the indices with no data point. Is that Ok for you ?

Comment: Yes. I made a small edit to combine the indices with and without data. Thanks!